SQL delight how to get SUM and last inserted data from a table in real time?
I need to access the sum of all data and the last inserted data in real-time with SQL Delight, how to achieve real-time updated data without adding new table?
CREATE TABLE my_table(
   id   TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   name TEXT NOT NULL,
   point REAL    DEFAULT 0.0,
   created_date TEXT NOT NULL
);

Get sum data:
getSum:
SELECT COALESCE(sum(point), 0) as total FROM my_table;

getLastData:
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY created_date LIMIT 1;

Inside viewModel:
private val _lastInserted = MutableStateFlow<MyTable?>>(null)
val lastInserted: StateFlow<MyTable?> = _lastInserted.asStateFlow()

private val _sum = MutableStateFlow<GetSum?>>(null)
val sum: StateFlow<GetSum?> = _sum.asStateFlow()

fun getTotal(){
   val result = repository.getSum()
   viewModelScoped.launch{
      result.collectLatest{ sum ->
         _sum.value = sum
      }
   }
}

fun getLasData(){
   val result = repository.getLastInserted()
   viewModelScoped.launch{
      result.collectLatest{ sum ->
         _lastInserted.value = sum
      }
   }
}

